# Select a price tab after refreshing using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an issue with my code. When my prices tab are empty I can select (or choose one) with a css highlight on. But when I refresh my prices tab with jQuery and ajax, the selection style doesn't work anymore.

When it is empty

here is my html code:

```js
$('#subcategories').on('change',function(){
    $.post('../inc/ajaxData.php',
        {subcat_id:$('#subcategories').val()},
        function(res){
            $('#price-tab').html(res);
    });
});
    
$('#pack-1').on('click', function(){

    $('#pack-1').addClass('pack-selected');
    $('#pack-2').removeClass('pack-selected');
    $('#pack-3').removeClass('pack-selected');
});

$('#pack-2').on('click', function(){

    $('#pack-2').addClass('pack-selected');
    $('#pack-1').removeClass('pack-selected');
    $('#pack-3').removeClass('pack-selected');
});

$('#pack-3').on('click', function(){

    $('#pack-3').addClass('pack-selected');
    $('#pack-1').removeClass('pack-selected');
    $('#pack-2').removeClass('pack-selected');
});
```

```html
<!-- PHP Begins : ajaxData.php -->

if(!empty($_POST['subcat_id'])){
    
    $subcat_id = $_POST['subcat_id'];
    
    $pack_query = "SELECT * FROM package WHERE id_sub = ".$subcat_id."";
    $pack_connexion = mysqli_query($connexion, $pack_query);
    if (!$pack_connexion){

        die("Défaut de connexion.". mysqli_error($connexion));                    
    } else {
        
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($pack_connexion);
        $_SESSION['pack_id'] = $row['pack_id'];
        $_SESSION['pack_name'] = $row['pack_name'];
        $_SESSION['pack_price'] = $row['pack_price'];
        $_SESSION['pack_option'] = $row['pack_option'];
        $_SESSION['pack_icon'] = $row['pack_icon'];
    ?>    
        <div class="form-group">
        <!-- col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->
        <div class="col-md-4 pricing-table-block">
        <!-- pricing-table-item -->
            <div class="pricing-table-item"  id="pack-a">

                <!-- pricing-table-title -->
                <div class="pricing-table-title">

                    <!-- pricing-table-icon -->
                    <div class="pricing-table-icon">
                        <i class="<?php echo $_SESSION['pack_icon']; ?>" style="color: #cd7f32;"></i>
                    </div><!-- /pricing-table-icon -->

                    <h3><?php echo $_SESSION['pack_name']; ?> </h3>

                </div><!-- /pricing-table-title -->

                <!-- pricing-table-price -->
                <div class="pricing-table-price">
                    <div><span class="pricing-table-value"><?php echo $_SESSION['pack_price']; ?><span class="pricing-table-sign">CAD</span></span></div>
                </div><!-- /pricing-table-price --> 

                <!-- pricing-table-features --> 
                <div class="pricing-table-features">

                    <ul>
                        <?php echo $_SESSION['pack_option']; ?>
                    </ul>

                </div><!-- /pricing-table-features -->

                <!--pricing-table-button--> 
                <div class="pricing-table-button">
                    <p title="" class="">* Projet ouvert au candidat pendant 7 jours</p>
                    <p title="" class="">* À réaliser en 21 jours max.</p>
                </div> 
                <!--/pricing-table-button--> 


            </div><!-- /pricing-table-item -->
        </div><!-- /col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->

        <!-- col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->
        <div class="col-md-4 pricing-table-block" >
            <!-- pricing-table-item -->
            <div class="pricing-table-item" id="pack-b"> 
            <?php 
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($pack_connexion);           
                $_SESSION['pack_id'] = $row['pack_id'];
                $_SESSION['pack_name'] = $row['pack_name'];
                $_SESSION['pack_price'] = $row['pack_price'];
                $_SESSION['pack_option'] = $row['pack_option']; 
                $_SESSION['pack_icon'] = $row['pack_icon']; 
            ?>

                <!-- pricing-table-ribbon-wrapper -->
                <div class="pricing-table-ribbon-wrapper">
                    <div class="pricing-table-ribbon">Meilleur choix</div>
                </div><!-- /pricing-table-ribbon-wrapper -->

                <!-- pricing-table-title -->
                <div class="pricing-table-title">

                    <!-- pricing-table-icon -->
                    <div class="pricing-table-icon">
                        <i class="<?php echo $_SESSION['pack_icon']; ?>" style="color: #C0C0C0;"></i>
                    </div><!-- /pricing-table-icon --> 

                    <h3><?php echo $_SESSION['pack_name']?></h3>

                </div><!-- /pricing-table-title -->


                <!-- pricing-table-price -->
                <div class="pricing-table-price">
                    <div><span class="pricing-table-value"><?php echo $_SESSION['pack_price']; ?><span class="pricing-table-sign">CAD</span></span></div>
                </div><!-- /pricing-table-price  -->


                 <!-- pricing-table-features --> 
                <div class="pricing-table-features">

                    <ul>
                        <?php echo $_SESSION['pack_option']; ?>
                    </ul>

                </div><!-- /pricing-table-features --> 

             <!--pricing-table-button--> 
                <div class="pricing-table-button">
                    <p title="" class="">* Projet ouvert au candidat pendant 7 jours</p>
                    <p title="" class="">* À réaliser en 41 jours max.</p>
                </div> 
                 <!--/pricing-table-button--> 


            </div><!-- /pricing-table-item -->
        </div><!-- /col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->


        <!-- col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->
        <div class="col-md-4 pricing-table-block">
            <!-- pricing-table-item -->
            <div class="pricing-table-item" id="pack-c"> 
            <?php 
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($pack_connexion);           
                $_SESSION['pack_id'] = $row['pack_id'];
                $_SESSION['pack_name'] = $row['pack_name'];
                $_SESSION['pack_price'] = $row['pack_price'];
                $_SESSION['pack_option'] = $row['pack_option'];
            ?>

                <!-- pricing-table-title -->
                <div class="pricing-table-title">

                    <!-- pricing-table-icon -->
                    <div class="pricing-table-icon">
                        <i class="<?php echo $_SESSION['pack_icon']; ?>" style="color: #ffd700;"></i>
                    </div><!-- /pricing-table-icon --> 
                    
                    <h3><?php echo $_SESSION['pack_name']; ?></h3>

                </div><!-- /pricing-table-title -->

                <!-- pricing-table-price -->
                <div class="pricing-table-price">
                    <div><span class="pricing-table-value"><?php echo $_SESSION['pack_price']; ?><span class="pricing-table-sign">CAD</span></span></div>
                </div><!-- /pricing-table-price  -->

                 <!--pricing-table-features--> 
                <div class="pricing-table-features">

                    <ul>
                        <?php echo $_SESSION['pack_option']; ?>
                    </ul>

                </div><!--/pricing-table-features--> 

                <!--pricing-table-button--> 
                <div class="pricing-table-button">
                    <p title="" class="">* Projet ouvert au candidat pendant 7 jours</p>
                    <p title="" class="">* À réaliser en 51 jours max.</p>
                </div> 
                 <!--/pricing-table-button--> 

            </div><!-- /pricing-table-item -->
        </div><!-- /col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->
        </div> 

        
 <?php        
    }
}
?>



<!-- HTML Begins -->

<div class="row" id="price-tab">
  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->
    <div class="col-md-4 pricing-table-block">
      <!-- pricing-table-item -->
      <div class="pricing-table-item" id="pack-1">

        <!-- pricing-table-title -->
        <div class="pricing-table-title">

          <!-- pricing-table-icon -->
          <div class="pricing-table-icon">
            <i class="far fa-file-code" style="color: #cd7f32;"></i>
          </div>
          <!-- /pricing-table-icon -->

          <h3>-</h3>

        </div>
        <!-- /pricing-table-title -->

        <!-- pricing-table-price -->
        <div class="pricing-table-price">
          <div><span class="pricing-table-value">-<span class="pricing-table-sign">CAD</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /pricing-table-price -->

        <!-- pricing-table-features -->
        <div class="pricing-table-features">

          <ul>
            -
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /pricing-table-features -->

        <!--pricing-table-button-->
        <div class="pricing-table-button">
          <p title="" class="">* Projet ouvert au candidat pendant 7 jours</p>
          <p title="" class="">* À réaliser en 21 jours max.</p>
        </div>
        <!--/pricing-table-button-->


      </div>
      <!-- /pricing-table-item -->
    </div>
    <!-- /col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->

    <!-- col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->
    <div class="col-md-4 pricing-table-block">
      <!-- pricing-table-item -->
      <div class="pricing-table-item" id="pack-2">

        <!-- pricing-table-ribbon-wrapper -->
        <div class="pricing-table-ribbon-wrapper">
          <div class="pricing-table-ribbon">Meilleur choix</div>
        </div>
        <!-- /pricing-table-ribbon-wrapper -->

        <!-- pricing-table-title -->
        <div class="pricing-table-title">

          <!-- pricing-table-icon -->
          <div class="pricing-table-icon">
            <i class="far fa-file-code" style="color: #C0C0C0;"></i>
          </div>
          <!-- /pricing-table-icon -->


          <h3>-</h3>

        </div>
        <!-- /pricing-table-title -->


        <!-- pricing-table-price -->
        <div class="pricing-table-price">
          <div><span class="pricing-table-value">-<span class="pricing-table-sign">CAD</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /pricing-table-price  -->


        <!-- pricing-table-features -->
        <div class="pricing-table-features">

          <ul>
            -
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /pricing-table-features -->

        <!--pricing-table-button-->
        <div class="pricing-table-button">
          <p title="" class="">* Projet ouvert au candidat pendant 7 jours</p>
          <p title="" class="">* À réaliser en 41 jours max.</p>
        </div>
        <!--/pricing-table-button-->


      </div>
      <!-- /pricing-table-item -->
    </div>
    <!-- /col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->


    <!-- col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->
    <div class="col-md-4 pricing-table-block">
      <!-- pricing-table-item -->
      <div class="pricing-table-item" id="pack-3">


        <!-- pricing-table-title -->
        <div class="pricing-table-title">

          <!-- pricing-table-icon -->
          <div class="pricing-table-icon">
            <i class="far fa-file-code" style="color: #ffd700;"></i>
          </div>
          <!-- /pricing-table-icon -->

          <h3>-</h3>

        </div>
        <!-- /pricing-table-title -->


        <!-- pricing-table-price -->
        <div class="pricing-table-price">
          <div><span class="pricing-table-value">-<span class="pricing-table-sign">CAD</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /pricing-table-price  -->


        <!--pricing-table-features-->
        <div class="pricing-table-features">

          <ul>
            -
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!--/pricing-table-features-->

        <!--pricing-table-button-->
        <div class="pricing-table-button">
          <p title="" class="">* Projet ouvert au candidat pendant 7 jours</p>
          <p title="" class="">* À réaliser en 51 jours max.</p>
        </div>
        <!--/pricing-table-button-->


      </div>
      <!-- /pricing-table-item -->
    </div>
    <!-- /col-md-4 pricing-table-block -->
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a lot of code but I just want you to get more details about that

Comment: You should try and shorten the PHP part to a [mcve] (and maybe convert it to HTML). That would make your question easier to answer.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to insert an image, do so: only the "enter image description here" was left and I deleted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$('#pack-1').click()` to register an event handler it adds the handler to only those elements which exists in the DOM when the code was executed.

Use delegation based event handlers like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#pack-1', function(){
        $('#pack-1').addClass('pack-selected');
        $('#pack-2').removeClass('pack-selected');
        $('#pack-3').removeClass('pack-selected');
    });
```